# What does "scroll event by window or content" mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I am new to JS and just started learning stuff.

I read this:  http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

I know the scrolling part but when we say "scroll by window or content" what do we actually mean? Are we saying a scroll event triggered by the height of a browser window  and by content do we mean html content?

Comment: It means the event can be fired by the `window` or by any element set with an `overflow` property set on it which causes a scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks! So fired by the window means browser height? and content means if you have enough that it causes the window to scroll?

Comment: in its simplest terms, yeah pretty much :)

Answer (score 1):

From the same page:

> The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a
>   different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also
>   to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set
>   to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less
>   than the height or width of its contents).